# Ubuntu terminal closes after running the script

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, terminal

This is a .sh file which the Ubuntu terminal runs then quits immediately. What is wrong with my script?

I don't know what my problem is – why the terminal closes after running the script and does not let me see the result. The file is shown here. Typing each command in the terminal is working, but putting them together in the file .sh, it has a problem as above.

```
echo 
echo $PATH
echo
nslookup www.fiu.edu
echo
netstate-a
echo
traceroute www.google.com
echo
ifconfig
```

Comment: are you running this from the terminal, or is this script in a file that you're clicking on? additionally, the command is "netstat", not "netstate-a".

Comment: Ditto — exactly how are you running this script?  See if you can describe the sequence of events more clearly.  What happens if you run a script with just one command in it?  What if you create a script file *with  **no** commands*, and run that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure how you are *running* this script, but I would re-write like so (I've also included comments):

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is a comment line, but the line above must be the first line
# and defines the shell that the rest of this script will use.

echo "PATH: ["$PATH"]"
# Personally, I like to include [] around vars so I can see 
# exactly what they are

# Run a few network related commands
nslookup www.fiu.edu

netstate -a

traceroute www.google.com

ifconfig

# Pause the script with a question. This will stop the script 
# from simply closing. Default to "y" as well so the user can 
# just hit the enter key to exit.
echo -n "Finished? [y/n](y) "
read ans

# Check what the user typed - if anything
if [ "$ans" = "" -o "$ans" = "Y" -o "$ans" = "y" ]
then
    # Exit with 0 to signify no issue.
    exit 0
else
    echo "All done, so exiting anyway :]"
    exit 0
fi
```